# name a series of formula automatically in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Hi I created a formula involving an offset function in a cell and dragged it over covering more than a hundred cells, my problem is i need to define each formula in a name manager.  Is there a way I can do it automatically?

Comment: Do you mean to create a named range for each column? If you want to avoid doing that you could create one range for the first column then reference the other columns using OFFSET(myRange,0,n) where myRange is the name of your range and n is the number of columns you want to offset by

Comment: I need to name the formula inside the cell not the column reference.